# Divisão entre numero inteiro e real retorna NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou recendo os valores inteiro (exemplo 350) e um numero real (exemplo 3,50), preciso dividir um pelo outro, precisamente (3,50 / 350) o resultado seria 0,01.

```
var tamanho = parseInt($("#tamanho").val());
var valor = $("#valor").val();
var valorMl = valor / tamanho;
console.log(valor, tamanho, valorMl);
```

`valor` retorna `3,50`.

`tamanho` retorna `350`.

`valorMl` retorna `NaN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o número vindo da caixa de texto for formatado com a `vírgula` representando o decimal, ele não vai funcionar. No javascript, este papel é o ponto `.`:

Você precisa substituir as vírgulas por pontos, e para garantir usar a função `parseFloat` que retorna sempre um número:

```js
function calc() {
  var tamanho = parseInt($("#tamanho").val());
  var valor = parseFloat($("#valor").val().replace(/\,/, '.'));
  var valorMl = valor / tamanho;
  console.log(valor, tamanho, valorMl);
}

calc();

$("#tamanho, #valor").on('input', calc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Tamanho:
<input type="text" value="350" id="tamanho">
<br>Valor:
<input type="text" value="3,50" id="valor">
```

Comment: Opa obrigado era isso mesma, eu podia também mudar na maskmoney do jquery, faz usei o replace pra fazer o calculo e no input ele continua aparecendo a virgula, obrigado @samirbraga, feliz ano novo!

Comment: De nada, @BrunoCabral. Feliz ano novo pra você também :).